# Why my multi thread program is slower than single thread program?

Tags: c, multithreading

I know that many people already ask of this topic, but I really do not understand why my program is slow even I do not calculate standard input and output.

This is my single thread program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LEN 30000
int **arr;

int main()
{
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int *) * LEN);
    for(int i=0;i<LEN;i++)
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * LEN);
    clock_t st, ed;
    st = clock();
    for(int i=0;i<LEN;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<LEN;j++)
            arr[i][j] = 1;
    ed = clock();
    printf("time : %ld\n", ed-st);
}
```

And this is my multi thread program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LEN 30000
int **arr;

void *thread_excute(void *thread_argv)
{
    int start = ((int *)thread_argv)[0];
    int height = ((int *)thread_argv)[1];
    for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<LEN;j++)
            arr[start+i][j] = 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int *) * LEN);
    for(int i=0;i<LEN;i++)
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * LEN);
    clock_t st, ed;
    st = clock();
    // thread = 4
    pthread_t *thread_num = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    int **argv = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 4);
    for(int t=0;t<4;t++)
    {
        argv[t] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
        argv[t][0] = t*(LEN/4);
        argv[t][1] = LEN/4;
        pthread_create(&thread_num[t], 0, thread_excute, (void *)argv[t]);
    }
    for(int t=0;t<4;t++)
        pthread_join(thread_num[t], 0);
    ed = clock();
    printf("time : %ld\n", ed-st);
}
```

This is program that fill 30000 * 30000 int array to 1.
I make multithread program that each thread fill different row of array.
So I guess multithread program will be faster than singlethread program.
But this is output.

```
// single thread program
time : 3782958
// multi thread program
time : 3997991
```

I run this program on Ubuntu 20.04, and I have 4 cpu cores.
And I compile this code by `gcc file.c -o file -lpthread`

I do not know why this happens.

Comment: First, try making the arrays larger.  There's significant overhead in creating threads, and with smaller arrays the speedup from parallelizing calculations can be hidden by the extra overhead.  Second, make sure your threads actually return something *calculated* - the compiler is free to optimize away operations that have no observable affects.

Comment: How do you compile this?

Comment: Don't know if it would be relevant in this particular example on your hardware, but cache-coherence is also something to be aware of.  If your different threads are accessing memory really spread out, they could be clobbering.  Each row is 120kB, assuming 4-byte ints.  And each row is allocated separately, so they aren't necessarily located contiguously to each other.

Comment: What was your command line for compiling the code?

Comment: And the time it takes to actually *create* your array - mapping the memory pages - will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the all comment. I compile this code by `gcc file.c -o file -lpthread` and my gcc version is 9.4.0

Comment: @ChristianGibbons So you mean each of my thread maybe read and write to memories which are located close, and it might occur false sharing problem?

Comment: If you change malloc to calloc I think would force single threaded mapping of memory. My box is not idle and hence suitable for benchmark runs but it seems to cut ~50% of the overhead.  It's now in the realm of measurement errors for me.  Suggest you add timing code into the each thread function so you can gauge overhead.

Comment: In terms of size, it's 30k x 30k matrix of ints and with sizeof(int) ==  4 that is 3.6 GB of memory.  It's fairly large, no?

Comment: If you change optimizing level to -O3 I see a 3x improvement in performance.

Comment: I also modified your multi-threaded program to take number of threads as an argument and ran it with 1 thread.  latter is t(multiple)/t(single) = ~2% to 4% slower (with calloc & -O3), and with 8 threads it is 230+% slower.  I think it's a cache/memory thing more than a thread creation overhead.

Comment: @AllanWind Thanks for suggesting some insights. I fixed my multithread code to check time of each thread. I can see this cut the overhead, but each thread is still slower than single thread. So I agree with your idea, it might be cache/mem thing...

Comment: To @ChristianGibbons point single threaded version with a one vs len * calloc ~50% overhead.  As expected the single calloc has much fewer page faults 2671 vs 879154.

Comment: You use `clock()` for your benchmark which is "approximation of processor time used by the program".  If I use (bash) time, I can no longer get reliable measurement showing a 8 thread version is slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the tweaked version of your multi-thread program:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LEN 30000
int **arr;

void *thread_excute(void *thread_argv) {
    // clock_t st, ed;
    // st = clock();
    int start = ((int *)thread_argv)[0];
    int height = ((int *)thread_argv)[1];
    int thread = ((int *)thread_argv)[2];
    for(int i=start; i<start+height; i++)
        for(int j=0;j<LEN; j++)
            arr[i][j] = 1;
    // ed = clock();
    // printf("%d %ld %ld %ld\n", thread, st, ed, ed-st);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    arr = calloc(1, sizeof(int *) * LEN);
    arr[0] = calloc(LEN, sizeof(int) * LEN);
    for(int i=1; i<LEN; i++)
        arr[i] = arr[0] + i * LEN;
    clock_t st, ed;
    unsigned threads = (argc == 2) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 4;
    pthread_t *thread_num = malloc(sizeof(int) * threads);
    st = clock();
    int **argv2 = malloc(sizeof(int *) * threads);
    for(int t=0; t<threads; t++) {
        argv2[t] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
        argv2[t][0] = t * (LEN/threads);
        argv2[t][1] = LEN/threads;
        argv2[t][2] = t;
        pthread_create(&thread_num[t], 0, thread_excute, (void *)argv2[t]);
    }
    for(int t=0; t<threads; t++)
        pthread_join(thread_num[t], 0);
    ed = clock();
    printf("%ld\n", ed-st);
}
```

If you build this with `-O3` and benchmark with (bash) time, I cannot no longer reliably get a lower multi-threaded run compared to the single threaded version (4 cores, 8 hyper threads):

| threads | clock | time (real) | time (sys) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| single | 352917 | 0m0.361s | 0m0.089s |
| multi 1 | 365564 | 0m0.373s | 0m0.273s |
| multi 2 | 524756 | 0m0.274s | 0m0.430s |
| multi 4 | 774477 | 0m0.215s | 0m0.589s |
| multi 8 | 1711224 | 0m0.331s | 0m1.136s |

My conclusion is that `clock()` is not be a good metric to measure "slower".  Your program is getting faster till we go from 4 to 8 thread (this laptop has 4 cores / 8 hyper threads).  Another take away is that the operating system does a lot more work to accomplish the same thing as the number of threads goes up.

Comment: Specifically, `clock()` on most platforms measures **CPU time**.  A program that completes in 2 seconds when running on 4 cores has used 8 seconds of CPU time.  Adding threads certainly won't reduce total CPU time, but it does reduce real time in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is very helpful for me. I should use the other function to check time.

Comment: I change my clock method to clock_gettime, and it work better.